# NAT444 on vodafone 3g

Tags: nat

I am using Huawei K3765 with vodafone as ISP. When i tested my IP with ipconfig, private IP is assigned to me. I dont think this device act as a router, since its just a 3g donle. This created the question that "am i behind NAT444?".
IP address from ipconfig: 10.135.237.173
IP address from dnsstuff: 42.104.63.55
One more question, From RFC 6598, address space "100.64.0.0/10" is reserved for NAT444. But mine starts with 10.?

Comment: An ISP not following RFCs? Shocking! But seriously, what's your question?

Comment: @faker My question is simple, why my ip is different?

Comment: You'll need to ask Vodafone that

Comment: RFCs are not law, companies can and do violate them on a regular basis. The only thing the RFCs do is provide a standard to ensure interoperability. If Vodafone or any other company does not want to ensure interoperability with the rest of the Internet then they have no reason to follow the RFCs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, cellular providers nearly universally uses carrier grade NAT. No, they are not forced to adhere to every RFC, thus using RFC1918 address ranges is perfectly possible.

What is your technical problem? Should it be that external servers see it as `42.104.63.55`: This is the whole point of NAT -  multiple systems can share the same external address.

Comment: I need to host a TCP server with this device. If i am behind carrier grade NAT, all inbound connection will be blocked. isn't it? In that case what is the solution?

Comment: There is no solution and I am quite certain that Vodafone's TOS prohibit running a server anyway. You can try to talk to them to see if they can/want help you but this is extremely unlikely.